# How to put 2 arraylists into one hashmap?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

So I'm making a plugin and I want to put two `ArrayList` (of two different teams) to one `Hashmap`, so I can get both of the teams in this method:

```
public static Teams getTeam(Player player) {

    if (!hasTeam(player))
        return null;
    return zombiesTeam.get(player) && survivorsTeam.get(player);

}
```

Here is the two `ArrayList` and a `Hashmap` that I want to have:

```
public static HashMap<zombiesTeam, survivorsTeam> playerTeams = new HashMap<zombiesTeam, survivorsTeam>(); 
public static ArrayList<Player> zombiesTeam = new ArrayList<Player>();
public static ArrayList<Player> survivorsTeam = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

P.S. I know that this code isn't correct

Please ask me for any further additional information

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean get both teams? i don't understand what you really expect to do this code?

Comment: You could use `Stream.concat().collection()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
public static HashMap<String, ArrayList<Player>> playerTeams = new HashMap<>();

playerTeams.put("zombies", zombiesTeam);
playerTeams.put("survivors", survivorsTeam );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent all your "teams" by a hashmap from the team name to the list of team members, I would suggest this:

```
// In the same class where zombiesTeam and survivorsTeam are declared
public static Map<String, List<Player>> getTeamsByName() {
  Map<String, List<Player>> teamsByName = new HashMap<>();
  teamsByName.put("zombiesTeam", zombiesTeam);
  teamsByName.put("survivors", survivorsTeam);
  return teamsByName;
}
```

However, be sure that you need to use static fields and methods. Your model doesn't suggest this.

For instance, you could rather declare a Team class and a Player class. Since you already have the Player class, here is how I would make the Team class:

```
public class Team {
  private String name;
  private Set<Player> teamMembers = new HashSet<>();

  public Team(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getName() {
   return this.teamName;
  }

  public Set<Player> getTeamMembers() {
    return this.teamMembers;
  }

  public addPlayer(Player player) {
   this.teamMembers.add(player);
  }

  public removePlayer(Player player) {
   this.teamMembers.remove(player);
  }

  public reset() {
   this.teamMembers.clear();
  }
}
```

Be sure to override equals and hashcode for HashSet and HashMap to work correctly. More information about this here:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equals-hashcode-methods-java/